# Database server setup guide

Tags: database-administration

Is there a good guide to setting up database servers, specifically MSSQL 2008 on Windows Server 2008, in a large organisation?

I'm sure I'm able to collect all the information I need myself, but if there's a well known guide, it would be nice to have it listed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TechNet is always the first place to go for these type of questions:

- [Planning a SQL Server Installation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500442.aspx)
- [Installing SQL Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500395.aspx)

Comment: Brilliant - thanks for that. I'm always on MSDN for dev work, but totally forgot about TechNet.

Comment: I do the exact opposite!  I live on Technet, and often forget about MSDN :)